# Add tag/label on top of images flutter with relative position

Tags: flutter, image, tags, instagram

I am building an Instagram clone (specifically image tag feature). I am able to put tags on top of images the user uploads but when the screen size/orientation/Zoom changes the tags does not reposition themselves.

Could anyone tell me how can I achieve this and store tag position so that when I load image again in user feed, I could be able to see tags on the image.

Comment: Sounds like a layout issue, can you show us your layout and how the tags sit on the images?

Comment: Same as the Instagram upload image feature.

Comment: Please paste code, can't help you before that. It might to layout issue, but need code to check

Comment: use tag text widget wrap with positioned widget into the stack widget

Comment: I am using positioned with stack rn, let me update the question with my code. Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the image and the label in a **Column** or a **Stack**. A Column will put **both** the tag and the image in the center while with a Stack you can align the image in the center and the text below. 
 Example with Column: 
`Column (children: [Image.asset('assets/myasset.png'), Text('My image'), ] ),` 
 Example with a Stack: 
 `Stack(children:[Center(child: Text('My Image')), Align(alignment:Alignment.bottomCenter,child: Image.asset('assets/myasset.png'))]),`

Answer (score 0):

Use Mediaquery:

example:

```
 double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
 double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

// Example: Change position based on screen height

double positionTop = screenHeight * 0.3;

// Example: Change position based on screen width

double positionLeft = screenWidth * 0.2;